# Как создать динамический параметр класса

Tags: c#, классы

Допустим есть сайт, на котором хранятся параметры товара. Например, шт, вес, длина и т.д. Логично предположить что таких параметров может быть туева куча и у разных товаров она разная. Заранее определить их в классе нет возможности, так как мы не знаем сколько их будет.
Например,

```
Item item = new Item();
item.Вес = ..;
item.Шт = ...;
```

Т.е. как сделать чтобы у нас появлялся доступ к параметрам?

Comment: Словарь не подходит?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

к примеру (динамические-используем словарь):

```
 class Product
 {
    private Dictionary<string, string> _properties;

    public Product()
    {
        this._properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            // здесь может быть исключение если нет ключа.
            return _properties[key];
        }
        set
        {
            this._properties[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if` в методе `set` не нужен. При присваивании по индексатору создается новый элемент или обновляется значение для указанного ключа. Т.о., достаточно `_properties[key] = value;`

Comment: @Vlad Спасибо забыл и исправил.

Comment: Ошибка CS0029 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "string" в "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>". WindowsFormsApp5

Comment: @Radzhab this._properties[key] = value; Проблема была .)